# how to suppress file change events while executing 'git merge' or 'git checkout branch'

Tags: git, filesystemwatcher

NodeJS fs.watch is very good to listen file events, we want to use it to automatically compile sass files to css files, or coffee scripts to js scripts.

But there is a problem confusing us. Since we use git, while executing 'git merge' or 'git checkout branch', there are a lot of file change events which should be filtered.

How to suppress these needless events?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to make sure any git operation (merge / checkout) set, through a wrapper or alias or git, some kind of flag (like a file '`git_operation_in_progress`').

If your listener of your [`fs.watchFile(filename, [options], listener)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) detects a change on *that* flag file, that same listener can detect, but ignore (ie take no action), changes for all other files, up until that '`git_operation_in_progress`' change again or disappear.

Comment: @springuper not that I know of.